# Trying to dedicate a channel to only sending pictures and reddit links

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Update: Problem with double condition solved. The Code Still Does Not Function.

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.author === client) return;
  if (message.channel.id === "605839623372931093") {
  if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
    if (!message.attachments.every(attachIsImage) || !message.content.includes("https://www.reddit.com/")) {
      (bulkDelete(message))
      (message.channel.send("This channel Only Supports Picture Messages or Reddit Links!"));
}}}});
```

It is worth noting that my code doesn't give out any errors, it just doesnt do anything.

If you would like to know more, just ask me and I'm willing to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OR` operator (`||`) to check if the message doesn't fullfil either of your conditions. Your `if` statement would then look like this:

```js
if (!message.attachments.every(attachIsImage) || !message.content.includes("https://www.reddit.com/")) {
  // Delete the message and let the user know about the channel rules
}
```